# Cant set headers after they are sent ALSO CASTError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I seem to be getting 2 errors.....

Here is the Route:

```
router.post("/event",  isLoggedIn, function (req,res){
// get data from form and add to events array
var title = req.body.title;
var date =  req.body.date;
var description = req.body.description;
var venue = req.body.venue;
var photo = req.body.photo;
var category = req.body.category;
//get user data to save to the event.
var owner = {
    id: req.user._id,
    username: req.user.username
};
var newEvent = {category: category, title: title, date: date, description: description, venue: venue, photos:{link: photo,date: date}, owner: owner};

//Create the event itself in the database, event will return the actual database event.
Event.create(newEvent, function(err, event){
    if (err) {
        console.log(err)
    } else {
        //This takes the event owner ID and saves it into the Event model
        console.log(event);
        event.owner.id = req.user._id;
        //This takes the event username and saves it into the Event model
        event.owner.username = req.user.username;
        event.save();
        //Save the event ID in the user document
        console.log(event);
        User.findByIdAndUpdate(
            req.user._id,
            {$push: {events:{"ObjectId": event._id}}},
            {save: true, upsert: true, new: true},
            function (err,newEventData){
                if(err){
                    console.log("error at saving the id ..." + err)
                    res.redirect("/dashboard");
                } else {
                    console.log(newEventData);
                }
            }
        );
        //Add the Event ID to the User model
        console.log (owner);
    };
});
res.redirect('events');
});
```

Here is the output of the console.log of the returned value from Mongoose and also the error.

```
The id of the user 583f30b1e5e7e376502762f5
Below are all the events pulled{ _id: 583f30b1e5e7e376502762f5,
  username: 'asdf',
  __v: 0,
  favoriteMoments: [],
  favoriteEvents: [],
  likeEvents: [],
  likeMoments: [],
  friends: [],
  moments: [],
  events: [],
  categories: [] }
{ __v: 0,
  title: 'asdf',
  description: 'asdf',
  _id: 583f3175b6a3b376a515c146,
  comments: [],
  photos: { link: '', date: null },
  moments: [],
  category: [ '' ],
  owner: { id: 583f30b1e5e7e376502762f5, username: 'asdf' } }
{ __v: 0,
  title: 'asdf',
  description: 'asdf',
  _id: 583f3175b6a3b376a515c146,
  comments: [],
  photos: { link: '', date: null },
  moments: [],
  category: [ '' ],
  owner: { id: 583f30b1e5e7e376502762f5, username: 'asdf' } }
{ id: 583f30b1e5e7e376502762f5, username: 'asdf' }
error at saving the idCastError: Cast to [ObjectId] failed for value "[{"ObjectId":"583f3175b6a3b376a515c146"}]" at path "events"
events.js:141
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:335:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (/var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:719:10)
    at ServerResponse.location (/var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:836:15)
    at ServerResponse.redirect (/var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:874:18)
    at /var/www/familysite.com/routes/eventRoute.js:67:29
    at /var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3388:16
    at /var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/mongoose/lib/model.js:3388:16
    at /var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/kareem/index.js:207:48
    at /var/www/familysite.com/node_modules/kareem/index.js:127:16
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:419:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:348:13)
```

Here is the schema of the Users Model:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    nickname: String,
    firstName: String,
    middleName: String,
    lastName: String,
    address: String,
    city: String,
    state: String,
    phone: Number,
    birthday: Date,
    birthplace: String,
    userCover: String,
    categories: Array,
    events: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
    }],
    moments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }],
    friends: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "User"
    }],
    likeMoments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }],
    likeEvents: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Event"
    }],
    favoriteEvents: [{
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Event"
    }],
    favoriteMoments: [{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: "Moments"
    }]
})
```

I have been getting no where with this Cast issue and now I have 2 errors which seems odd... getting very frustrated at this point and unsure where to go.

In the end, I have route that needs to create an event, save it event ID to the user that created it and then go to the `/event` page and display the data for each event.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the first block of code about 3/4 the way down...

this line:

```
{$push: {events:{"ObjectId": event._id}}},
```

Should look like this:

```
{$push: {events:{_id: event._id}}},
```

Thats it! so `_id` is how you tell it to be an ID.

Comment: You have other issues as well, you're redirecting twice if an error happens, that's why you get "headers sent" errors. Fixing the database error fixes the other problem .... *for now*, but you still have an error that will come back to haunt you whenever your database queries fail.

Comment: @adeneo Oh! Thanks for pointing that out. So your saying that me having an exit to `/dashboard` then it exits and goes to `/events` right? How would you handle that kind of a situation where you want to push different pages in a callback? Would you `return`? Or is that just as bad.